# Tried to Extend EditForm, But ChildContent is not rendering

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have tried to extend **EditForm** like

```
    MyEditFormBase: EditForm
    {
    }
```

and in **MyEditForm.razor**

```
    @inherits MyEditFormBase
    @ChildContent
```

when i use this like

```
    <MyEditForm Model="TestModel">
<div>
    <InputText @bind-Value="TestModel.Name"></InputText>
</div>
    </MyEditForm>
```

this renders like

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditContext]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EditForm's ChildContent is not a regular RenderFragment, but a generic RenderFragment of type RenderFragment<EditContext> (also commonly referred to as a Template).

In order to render that, you have to pass the argument like so:

```
@ChildContent(EditContext)
```

The advantage of such a template is that you can then access the EditContext object from the child content via @context.

Comment: `<InputText @bind-Value="TestModel.Name"></InputText>` this line throws System.NullReferenceException

Comment: as i can see my approach is not rendering form tag, this causes above issue

Comment: Is your project targeting .Net Core 3.x? If yes, consider upgrading your project to .Net 5 which came out just this week. This may fix the issue.

Comment: this is .net 5 project